# How to fix white color git bash integrated terminal?

Tags: git, terminal, visual-studio-code

I'm setting up a new terminal git bash in my vscode but all output inside terminal text is white how can i fix it to render syntax color code?

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56485592/bash-terminal-white-colors-in-integrated-terminal-vscode

Comment: @Mark Thanks for your reply but where's the answer ? the AShu2 comment is about color theme that couldn't fix my problem

Comment: No answer, but a question to keep an eye on in case one comes along.

Comment: is there any forum or something else related to my question to find out answer? i couldn't find vscode forum